# How to use the remote control in Flutter or activate a controller on the TV?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

E created a mobile flutter app and I ran it on my tv box that uses Android and the app looks good, but when I try to use the remote control to use it does not work it stays static and does not move anywhere, but if I use a mouse it works well, they could help me solve this problem as I could make use of the mouse on the tv or use the remote control.

I followed this example [text](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-for-apple-tv-756fcd5e8113), but it did not help me the total for the external buttons to my screen works with the enter but not with the control and does not select the widgets on the screen

Comment: Did you follow the links in the article and implement what it told you? If so, can you show us?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your MaterialApp with shortcut widget as follows:

```
Shortcuts(
    shortcuts: <LogicalKeySet, Intent>{
      LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.select): const ActivateIntent(),
    },
    child: MaterialApp())
```

"LogicalKeyboardKey.select" is the OK button on your remote TV.
The arrow keys is working by default.
If you need special function for a button you can use CallbackShortcuts as follows:

```
CallbackShortcuts(
    bindings: {
      const SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.contextMenu): () =>
          print("Menu button is pressed ..."),
    },
    child: Scaffold())
```

Also, you can use bind KeyEvent inside statefull widget as follows:

```
bool _onKey(KeyEvent event) {
  print("Pressed key is : ${event.logicalKey}");
  return false;
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  ServicesBinding.instance.keyboard.addHandler(_onKey);
}

@override
void dispose() {
  ServicesBinding.instance.keyboard.removeHandler(_onKey);
  super.dispose();
}
```