# Remote Control in Flutter Tizen Native TV App

Tags: flutter, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio

We have developed a Flutter native app for Tizen, featuring two webviews that load YouTube.com and Netflix.com, covering the entire screen in splits. We have successfully deployed and run the app on the TV, with the webviews loading properly. However, we are facing an issue where we cannot use the TV’s remote control to navigate through the content in the webviews. Interestingly, when we connect an external mouse via USB, we can see the cursor, and navigation works seamlessly.

We are seeking guidance on how to add a cursor, similar to the one in the Internet/Browser app, that can be used to navigate through the content in the webviews.

Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is [awkeyboardlistener-widget](https://flutteragency.com/rawkeyboardlistener-widget/)  or [how-to-use-the-remote-control-in-flutter-or-activate-a-controller-on-the-tv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75656486/how-to-use-the-remote-control-in-flutter-or-activate-a-controller-on-the-tv)answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone seeing these answer in feature check the [how-to-use-the-remote-control-in-flutter-or-activate-a-controller-on-the-tv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75656486/how-to-use-the-remote-control-in-flutter-or-activate-a-controller-on-the-tv) and [raw-key-board-listener-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76673938/raw-key-board-listener-flutter) ,because by the time you read this answer this already posted answer may have added some better points.

now 1st you need to listen for remote control events in the flutter app and then look for the events and do the performance accordingly .

in the below code i tried to answer you question but i have not tried the below code by self so pleas comment the result if it solves the issue or not ,so that other can have ease .

```
    RawKeyboardListener(
      focusNode: FocusNode(),
      onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
      if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
        if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp) {
          //code to mov cursor to up
        } else if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown) {
          //mov cursor to down
        } else if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowLeft) {
          //mov cursor to left
        } else if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowRight) {
          //mov cursor to right
        }
      }
    },
      child: WebView(WebViewController _controller;

WebView(
  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
    _controller = controller;
  },
)


_controller.scrollBy(x: deltaX, y: deltaY);
      ),)
```

as i already said i did not run and check the code so i welcome any edit or suggestion from any one .

EDIT:

for perform select/click event use the below approch;

```
    if(event is RawKeyUpEvent){//as far as i know it should be in RawKeyUpEvent but if did not work then try to log the event 
//or simply try with RawKeyDownEvent  
    if(event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.select){
    //perform click logic
    }
    }
```

you can put this code in the same  `onKey: (RawKeyEvent event)` if else logic to use.

as a addon/alternat to above answer please take a look at following block (from [LogicalKeyboardKey-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/LogicalKeyboardKey-class.html) and adding it here to make sure feature ability of this content).

> **RawKeyEvent**: the keyboard event object received by widgets that listen to keyboard events.
>
> **Focus.onKey**: the handler on a widget that lets you handle key events.
>
> **RawKeyboardListener**: a widget used to listen to keyboard events (but not handle them).

```
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    
    /// Flutter code sample for [LogicalKeyboardKey].
    
    void main() => runApp(const KeyExampleApp());
    
    class KeyExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const KeyExampleApp({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Key Handling Example')),
            body: const MyKeyExample(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyKeyExample extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyKeyExample({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<MyKeyExample> createState() => _MyKeyExampleState();
    }
    
    class _MyKeyExampleState extends State<MyKeyExample> {
      // The node used to request the keyboard focus.
      final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
      // The message to display.
      String? _message;
    
      // Focus nodes need to be disposed.
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _focusNode.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      // Handles the key events from the Focus widget and updates the
      // _message.
      KeyEventResult _handleKeyEvent(FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent event) {
        setState(() {
          if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.keyQ) {
            _message = 'Pressed the "Q" key!';
          } else {
            if (kReleaseMode) {
              _message =
                  'Not a Q: Pressed 0x${event.logicalKey.keyId.toRadixString(16)}';
            } else {
              // As the name implies, the debugName will only print useful
              // information in debug mode.
//pass the if else logic here for/as key press event you want to

              _message = 'Not a Q: Pressed ${event.logicalKey.debugName}';
            }
          }
        });
        return event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.keyQ
            ? KeyEventResult.handled
            : KeyEventResult.ignored;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final TextTheme textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
        return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: DefaultTextStyle(
            style: textTheme.headlineMedium!,
            child: Focus(
              focusNode: _focusNode,
              onKey: _handleKeyEvent,
              child: ListenableBuilder(
                listenable: _focusNode,
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
                  if (!_focusNode.hasFocus) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
                      },
                      child: const Text('Click to focus'),
                    );
                  }
                  return Text(_message ?? 'Press a key');
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

going through [native/flutter](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/native/flutter.html) could be helpful .

Comment: Hi @Rainy,
Thank you so much for the answer. We are able to retrieve the events and move the cursor. Now, we want to add a click event which will be triggered on pressing the 'Enter' button on the Remote. Can you please help us with that?

Comment: try the edit part for enter key / click event and let me know the result  ?

Comment: Once the WebView widget gets a focus (by simulating a touch), all key events will be handled by the WebView and thus the software cursor will stop working. As far as I know there is currently no way to release the focus from the Tizen WebView without using a pointer device.

Comment: Hi Rainy,
We were able to send a click event to the webview on pressing the enter key but, as mentioned by @SwiftKim, we are losing the control over the RawKeyboardListener and indeed the cursor stops working.

Comment: Is there any alternative that you guys can suggest? We are open to switch to .Net as well, if this functionality can be achieved.

Comment: If you want to simulate an event at specific coordinates, you can use GestureBinding(in your LogicalKeyboardKey.select event).

GestureBinding.instance.handlePointerEvent(PointerDownEvent(
  position: Offset(x, y),
));
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
GestureBinding.instance.handlePointerEvent(PointerUpEvent(
  position: Offset(x, y),
));

Comment: As @SwiftKim said, if the webView takes the Focus, the KeyEvent is taken by the Webview.
Therefore, after generating a gesture, you can unfocus the entire focus by unfocus() of the context where the webview is located.

FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); // or focus on custom(?) cursor.

Comment: please you all go through the edit part i added some block that i found on the support page (link of that is also added) , i welcome any suggestion made by any of us in this regards.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code. We tried .unfocus() suggested by jsuya & it is working fine now. We will also go through the links shared by you.

Comment: We have a webview loading youtube.com, and we're attempting to search for something. Is there a way to detect when the keyboard opens up? We're experiencing an issue where, when the keyboard pops up, we're unable to use the navigation keys on the remote.

Comment: please post new question with this specific issue so that there you can describe problem probably and lot more chance to get many helpful answer also for others who will be searching with that specific problem in feature will get better access to it.